# dompdf inserts blank page at end of document

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm generating a pdf document using dompdf 0.6.0, and have a strange issue where a blank page is being created at the end. My (simplified) html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>PDF</title>
<style type="text/css">
@page{ margin: 0;}

.page{
    width: 612px; 
    height: 792px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica; 
    position: relative; 
    color: #545554;
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page" style="background-image: url(page1.jpg);">
...
</div>

<div class="page" style="background-image: url(page2.jpg);"></div>

<div class="page" style="background-image: url(page3.jpg); color: white;">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first three pages look amazing, but there is a blank page at the end. I've read dompdf is picky about nesting and compliance and such, but the html is super clean and checks out.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Turns out the end `</body>` and `</html>` tags were causing the extra page. I removed them, and results are as expected.

I'd imagine its a problem with dompdf, but I spent quite awhile trying to solve the issue and figured this might be of help to others.

**Update:**

As Joe mentions in the comments, moving the `</body>` and `</html>` tags to the same line as your closing `</div>` works, and remains valid html.

Comment: I think the problem is not caused by the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags, but actually by the newline that comes after the closing `</div>` tag. Putting both the `</body>` and `</html>` on the same line as the last `</div>` will also work.

Comment: Interesting. Good catch @Joe. I'll try to verify that and update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I would have never in a million years thought to look at the closing html and body tags.

Comment: This, and maybe even a `trim()` on the html string you're about to transform into PDF. An empty space after `</html>` could make your head ache :)

Comment: I solved this issue exchanging <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>'; to '<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>';

Answer (score 16):

For me the fix was to remove any whitespace between tags.

```
 $html = preg_replace('/>\s+</', "><", $html);
```

Comment: Yep, that was it for me as well

Comment: thanks it was driving me crazy, but for me it was adding a before page blank

Comment: For me it was ```body {  height: 100%;}```. Removing ``` height: 100%;``` fixed the issue

Answer (score 9):

This happens because of the css you have written `page-break-after: always;` for `page` class.
The above style will do a page break after your last page also and dompdf creates a blank page at the end.

Another solution is to write a separate css style for your last page excluding `page-break-after: always;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>PDF</title>
<style type="text/css">
@page{ margin: 0;}

.page{
    width: 612px; 
    height: 792px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica; 
    position: relative; 
    color: #545554;
    page-break-after: always;
}
.last-page{
   width: 612px; 
   height: 792px; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica; 
   position: relative; 
   color: #545554;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page" style="background-image: url(page1.jpg);">
...
</div>

<div class="page" style="background-image: url(page2.jpg);"></div>

<div class="last-page" style="background-image: url(page3.jpg); color: white;">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: adding `.page:last-child { page-break-after: unset; }` also works

Answer (score 2):

In my case it occurred because the content was bigger than the paperSet(). If the content pass at least 1px, dompdf automatically creates another sheet. So you always need to set sizes according the paperSet() proportion you set.

For example:
Paper A4 is 210mmx297mm. To make it easier, I recommend to use 'mm' instead of 'px'. Then you can create your divs and add their heights summing them all and making sure it is within 297mm.

To know the papers sizes you can see in this site:

https://papersizes.io/

Answer (score 1):

if you have array variable then set this condition in `youtpdfhtml.blade.php`:

```
@if($key<($total-1))
  <div class="page-break"></div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove,
body</> and html</> end tag end of the page with extra line space. And I hope you can remove the extra blank page from the pdf.

Comment: the 7+ year old accepted answer already says the same thing, and also provides more info. How is your answer helpful in any way to anybody?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an array to store and output your HTML code, and still getting the error, you can remove the last page including page breaks in all pages except the last one, using count() function.

```
$html='';
$i = 0; //counter
$len = count($output_array);// lenght of the array
foreach($output_array as $output)
{   //store the html in a variable to use it in dompdf

    $html.= $output;

    if ($i < $len - 1) 
    { //if the counter is less than the lenght of the array, add a page break.
      $i++; 
      $html.=' <div class="page_break"></div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Filip Molcik suggested the solution. This is how I implemented this.

```
$view = view('layouts.qr-pdf');
$html = $view->render();
$html = preg_replace('/>\s+</', "><", $html);
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);

return $pdf->download('asd.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding
`margin-bottom: -20px;` to the `main` or `div` tag solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and resolved by changing the page height from -

min-height: 297 mm to min-height: 290 mm

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because i had a "min-height: 100%;" in a css file. Remove it for not have the extra blank page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).